# MongoDB: Why is my scannedObjects value high even all fields of the query are indexed?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, query-performance

I am indexing three fields on a collection, one of which is an array. I am running a query on these three fields and the query takes more than a second with 300K fields on the collection. When I call explain on the query, I see that my index is being used correctly, but the number of scannedObjects is very high. I guess this is the reason behind the low performance.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c8f110389a46153866d82e"),
    "mmt" : [ 
        "54944cfd90671810ccbf2552", 
        "54c64029038d8c3aff41ad6d", 
        "54c64029038d8c3aff41ad73", 
        "54c8f151038d8c3aff453669", 
        "54c8f151038d8c3aff45366d"
    ],
    "p" : 8700,
    "sui" : "3810d5cf-3032-4a77-9715-a42e010e569c"
    /* also some more fields */
}
```

With this index:

```
{
    "sui" : 1,
    "p" : 1,
    "mmt" : 1
}
```

I am trying to run this query:

```
db.my_coll.find(
{
    "mmt" : { "$all" :
        [
            "54944cfd90671810ccbf2552", "54ac1db0e3f494afd4ded4c8", "54ac1db1e3f494afd4ded66a", "54ac1db1e3f494afd4ded66b", "54c8b671038d8c3aff453649", "54c8f154038d8c3aff45368f", "54c8f154038d8c3aff453694"
        ]
},
    "sui" : { "$ne" : "bde0f517-b942-4823-b2c8-a41900f46641" },
    "p": { $gt: 100, $lt: 1000 }
}

).limit(1000).explain()
```

The result of the explain is:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor sui_1_p_1_mmt_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 16,
    "nscannedObjects" : 14356,
    "nscanned" : 129223,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 14356,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 129223,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1009,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1276,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "sui" : [ 
            [ 
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }, 
                "bde0f517-b942-4823-b2c8-a41900f46641"
            ], 
            [ 
                "bde0f517-b942-4823-b2c8-a41900f46641", 
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ],
        "p" : [ 
            [ 
                -Infinity, 
                1000
            ]
        ],
        "mmt" : [ 
            [ 
                "54944cfd90671810ccbf2552", 
                "54944cfd90671810ccbf2552"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "shopkrowdMongo:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "LIMIT",
        "works" : 129224,
        "yields" : 1009,
        "unyields" : 1009,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 16,
        "needTime" : 129207,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                "works" : 129224,
                "yields" : 1009,
                "unyields" : 1009,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 16,
                "needTime" : 129207,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "children" : [ 
                    {
                        "type" : "FETCH",
                        "works" : 129224,
                        "yields" : 1009,
                        "unyields" : 1009,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "advanced" : 16,
                        "needTime" : 129207,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "forcedFetches" : 0,
                        "matchTested" : 16,
                        "children" : [ 
                            {
                                "type" : "IXSCAN",
                                "works" : 129223,
                                "yields" : 1009,
                                "unyields" : 1009,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "advanced" : 14356,
                                "needTime" : 114867,
                                "needFetch" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "keyPattern" : "{ sui: 1.0, p: 1.0, mmt: 1.0 }",
                                "isMultiKey" : 1,
                                "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['sui']: [MinKey, \"bde0f517-b942-4823-b2c8-a41900f46641\"), (\"bde0f517-b942-4823-b2c8-a41900f46641\", MaxKey], field #1['p']: [-inf.0, 1000.0), field #2['mmt']: [\"54944cfd90671810ccbf2552\", \"54944cfd90671810ccbf2552\"]",
                                "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                                "dupsTested" : 14356,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                                "matchTested" : 0,
                                "keysExamined" : 129223,
                                "children" : []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The number of items found is 16 but the number of scannedObjects is 14356. I do not understand why mongodb scans so much documents even though all the fields of the query are indexed.

1. Why is mongodb scanning so much objects?
2. How can I get the results of this query faster?

The mmt array I am using does not grow or shrink over time, but the number of elements in it varies between 5 - 15. I need to query this field with several combinations of $in, $all and $nin. Number of items in this collection will probably grow over 30M. Is there a way to reliably get fast results for this scenario?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried removing sui field and the $ne query. The updated explain:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor p_1_mmt_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 17,
    "nscannedObjects" : 16338,
    "nscanned" : 16963,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 16338,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 33930,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 265,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 230,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "p" : [ 
            [ 
                -Infinity, 
                1000
            ]
        ],
        "mmt" : [ 
            [ 
                "54944cfd90671810ccbf2552", 
                "54944cfd90671810ccbf2552"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "shopkrowdMongo:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "LIMIT",
        "works" : 16966,
        "yields" : 265,
        "unyields" : 265,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 17,
        "needTime" : 16947,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                "works" : 16966,
                "yields" : 265,
                "unyields" : 265,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 17,
                "needTime" : 16947,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "children" : [ 
                    {
                        "type" : "FETCH",
                        "works" : 16965,
                        "yields" : 265,
                        "unyields" : 265,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "advanced" : 17,
                        "needTime" : 16947,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "forcedFetches" : 0,
                        "matchTested" : 17,
                        "children" : [ 
                            {
                                "type" : "IXSCAN",
                                "works" : 16964,
                                "yields" : 265,
                                "unyields" : 265,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "advanced" : 16338,
                                "needTime" : 626,
                                "needFetch" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "keyPattern" : "{ p: 1.0, mmt: 1.0 }",
                                "isMultiKey" : 1,
                                "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['p']: [-inf.0, 1000.0), field #1['mmt']: [\"54944cfd90671810ccbf2552\", \"54944cfd90671810ccbf2552\"]",
                                "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                                "dupsTested" : 16338,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                                "matchTested" : 0,
                                "keysExamined" : 16963,
                                "children" : []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The query performed better, but scannedObjects is still very high.

Comment: Remember the scanned objects is nothing more than a counter, as such if you scan a subdocument it will be much higher than the returned amount

Answer (score 2):

I think marcinn was right to single out the `$ne` as the most likely culprit, but  update 1 shows us the `$all` is also a problem. The query is using the `mmt` portion of the index to find documents containing one of the values in the array and then must scan the rest of the `mmt` array to verify that all of the values in the `$all` array are in the `mmt` array of a potentially matching document. This means the potentially matching document must be loaded and scanned, so it counts as a scannedObject. To demonstrate this behavior very clearly, consider the following example:

```
> db.test.drop()
> for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) db.test.insert({ "x" : [1, 2] })
> for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) db.test.insert({ "x" : [1, 3] })
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "x" : 1 })
> db.test.find({ "x" : { "$all" : [1, 2] } }).explain(true)
```

This shows `n = 100` and `nscanned = nscannedObjects = 200` resulting from using the value 1 as both index bounds, while the logically equivalent query

```
> db.test.find({ "x" : { "$all" : [2, 1] } }).explain(true)
```

shows `n = nscanned = nscannedObjects = 100` with both index bounds having the value 2.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you. Can you suggest a way to solve this problem in a scalable way?

Comment: `$ne` is not selective and can't be expected to scale well. What version of MongoDB are you using? The performance trip-up with `$all` was addressed in [SERVER-1000](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1000). The resolution was that the situation is handled by index intersection, which is a feature of MongoDB >= 2.6. It might be worth reconsidering the schema design to be able to write a more scalable query. If you like, you should sk a separate question explaining the use case behind your document structure and queries and we will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is because $ne cannot use indexes (efficiently). So your index is used only because first you query by mnt field and then its reading

> Some query operations are not selective. These operations cannot use
>   indexes effectively or cannot use indexes at all.
>
> The inequality operators $nin and $ne are not very selective, as they
>   often match a large portion of the index. As a result, in most cases,
>   a $nin or $ne query with an index may perform no better than a $nin or
>   $ne query that must scan all documents in a collection

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization/

Comment: I removed sui. The query performed better, but scannedObjects is still very high. I included the new explain in the question.